# three js raycast needing to be async

Tags: three.js

Here is a weird issue I am facing:

I have some code that updates some properties on a three js perspective camera, and then sends a raycast into the world hitting a plane in the `xz` space. Nothing particularly fancy about it. But, the issue seems to be that if I raycast after setting the properties then the origin of the ray ends up at `(0,0,0)`, and if I make it async by waiting 100ms then the origin is correcly set to camera origin.

```js
            camera.fov = s.fieldOfViewDeg[1]; //top to bottom
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 0)
            camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0) //the quaternion is relative and not absolute, so a reset is needed
            camera.applyQuaternion(new THREE.Quaternion(...q))

            camera.translateZ(15)
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            const plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
            const world = new THREE.Mesh(plane, await materials.getBasicMat());
            world.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
            world.position.y = (3.432 / 2) - 0.0001
            scene.add(world)

            new Raycaster(camera).cast(0, 0, [world])
            setTimeout(() => {
                new Raycaster(camera).cast(0, 0, [world])
            }, 100)
```

the `Raycaster.cast` is pretty straightforwards as well

```js
    cast(x: number, y: number, objects: any[]) {
        const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        raycaster.ray.origin = this.camera.position.clone()
        raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(x, y), this.camera)
        const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false)
        console.log(intersects)
    }
```

So I find it weird that that code gives me 2 completely different console outputs (from `Raycaster.cast`)

Is there some method somewhere that I can't find that is async and that I need to wait for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Raycaster.setFromCamera()` will overwrite the internal ray's origin so there is no point set the `origin` property manually.

Frame-late issues like you have described usually happen because the world matrix of your camera isn't up-to-date. So before calling `setFromCamera()`, do this:

```js
camera.updateMatrixWorld();
```

Besides, do not create an instance of `Raycaster` every time `cast()` is called. Create a single instance and reuse it in your app. Same for the object that holds the pointer coordinates.